# docker-composeで構築したrails 環境で rails db すると root パスワードを求められる。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, postgresql, docker-compose

データベース等をcreateした後に `rails db` でデータベースのコンソールに入ろうとすると　`Password for user root:` と表示されてパスワードの入力を求められます。 postgressというユーザは設定していますが、　rootというユーザは設定した覚えがないので、どうしたらパスワード入力を回避できるのでしょうか？
`root`, `postgress` と適当に入力しても `psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "root"` と表示されます。

ご存知の方、教えて下さるととても助かります。
宜しくお願い致します。

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.6.3
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  build-essential \
  libpq-dev \
  nodejs \
  postgresql-client \
  yarn


WORKDIR /sample-sample
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock /sample-sample
RUN bundle install
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  db-data:

services:
  web:
    build: .
    # portsは -pの役割
    ports:
      - '8888:8888'
    # volumesは -vの役割
    volumes:
      - '.:/sample-sample'
    # 環境変数に設定される
    environment:
      - 'DATABASE_PASSWORD=postgres'

    # ttyは -itのtを意味してる
    tty: true
    # -iを意味してる
    stdin_open: true
    # 先にdbを作成して下さいと指定する。
    depends_on:
      - db
    # webからdbにアクセスできるようになる。
    links:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - 'POSTGRES_USER=postgres'
      - 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres'

    # コンテナが削除されてもデータは残るようにローカル側のフォルダに保存するように設定する。
    # 下記のようなフォルダパスはなくdocker側でデータが管理される。実際のローカル環境からはアクセス出来ない。
    # これをローカルで管理できるように変更したい。
    # .に変更したみたけど、権限の関係かdbがエラーで落ちるようになった。。
    volumes:
      - 'db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
```

railsのデータベース設定
`config/database.yml`

```
# PostgreSQL. Versions 9.3 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On macOS with Homebrew:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
# On macOS with MacPorts:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem 'pg'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  host: db
  user: postgres
  port: 5432
  password: <%= ENV.fetch("DATABASE_PASSWORD")%>
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: sample_sample_development

  # The specified database role being used to connect to postgres.
  # To create additional roles in postgres see `$ createuser --help`.
  # When left blank, postgres will use the default role. This is
  # the same name as the operating system user that initialized the database.
  #username: sample_sample

  # The password associated with the postgres role (username).
  #password:

  # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
  # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
  # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
  #host: localhost

  # The TCP port the server listens on. Defaults to 5432.
  # If your server runs on a different port number, change accordingly.
  #port: 5432

  # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
  #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

  # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
  #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
  #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
  # Defaults to warning.
  #min_messages: notice

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: sample_sample_test

# As with config/credentials.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password as a unix environment variable when you boot
# the app. Read https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full rundown on how to provide these environment variables in a
# production deployment.
#
# On Heroku and other platform providers, you may have a full connection URL
# available as an environment variable. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="postgres://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# You can use this database configuration with:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
#
production:
  <<: *default
  database: sample_sample_production
  username: sample_sample
  password: <%= ENV['SAMPLE_SAMPLE_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

Comment: エラーに直接関連があるか分かりませんが、Dockerfile の `COPY` 行は引数が３つあってこの書き方では正しくないと思います。複数ファイルをコピーしたいならワイルドカードを使うか一行ずつに分ける必要があるでしょう。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user: postgres`
　↓
`username: postgres`

じゃないですか？

したの production と同じ書き方してみればいいんだと思います

---

```
environment:
      - 'POSTGRES_USER=postgres'
      - 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres'
```

にはいってるので

`password: <%= ENV.fetch("DATABASE_PASSWORD")%>`
↓
`password: <%= ENV.fetch("POSTGRES_PASSWORD")%>`

にすれば環境変数から拾えると思います

Comment: おお〜ありがとうございます。上手く行きました。
これって毎回パスワード聞かれないようにしたり可能でしょうか？

Comment: これはpostgressコンテナ側の環境変数なので受け取れない気がします。
`rails db` を実行したら 
```
(erb):25:in `fetch': Cannot load database configuration: (KeyError)
key not found: "POSTGRES_PASSWORD"
``` 
とエラーが表示されます。

Comment: environment:
      - 'DATABASE_PASSWORD=postgres'
に入ってるのでこれを使用すればいい気もするんですが、なぜかパスワードを要求されます。

Comment: `rails db -p` で自動で読み込んでくれるようになりました。ありがとうございます！